# Terminal not working, while everything else does

Tags: pi-4, terminal, lxterminal

I recently booted up my Raspberry Pi after a few months. Everything seems to work (I'm posting this question from it!), except for the terminal: it doesn't work at all.

I open LXTerminal, and it essentially functions like an append-only text file, with no response to any commands. How do I fix this?

Comment: Check if you have terminal configured to run a command at start (other than your shell...)

Comment: Thank you! This was the issue--`.bashrc` was running a script which was hanging for some reason, making every terminal window appear broken!

Answer (score 0):

When terminal opens, by default it starts a shell, as set for your account.  However, it can also be told both on the command line and in its internal configuration to open something else instead.

The shell itself runs a number of init scripts when it starts.  The bash shell in particular runs `/etc/bash.bashrc`, things in `/etc/profile.d`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc` and possibly others.  (A complete list of defaults can be found in the bash man page, and additional scripts not listed in the man page may be sourced from those defaults.) A command in any of these locations can hang or run slowly and appear unresponsive.